# Changing Datatype within an already existing SharedPreference Value

Tags: java, android, string, sharedpreferences, classcastexception

I am in the process of cleaning up some bad coding choices in some really old apps.  In one of the first apps I did, it has a user login.  So, I use `SharedPreferences` to store the `user_id`.  This should have been a `long` all along.  Unfortunately, I originally stored it as a `String`.

I am going back and correcting this.  However, I of course get a `ClassCastException` since I am trying to pull out a `String` as a `long`.

This is my code on how it works AFTER changing it:

```
public static void setLoggedInUserId(Context ctx, long id) {
    Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
    editor.putLong(PREF_LOGGEDIN_USER_USERID, id);
    editor.apply();
}

public static long getLoggedInUserId(Context ctx) {
    // need to handle String to long conversion here?
    return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getLong(PREF_LOGGEDIN_USER_USERID, 0);
}
```

What is the cleanest way to handle this so it is as transparent as possible to the user (I don't want to force a log out if possible).

**EDIT**

As I am typing this, is a a good solution?

`return  Long.valueOf(getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(PREF_LOGGEDIN_USER_USERID, 0));`

*A problem*:  This would only work the first time to workaround old data; because after that, the preference would be a `long` based on the setter method.

Next best option:  Can I test the type stored in the `preference`, maybe with a `typeof`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In `getLoggedInUserId`, catch the class cast exception
2. Read the (String) value of the shared preference and convert it with `Long.parseLong()`
3. Create an editor, `put` the long value, and commit.

This code will run exactly once and then you will no longer have to worry about edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

put this in your MainActivity before this value is called for the first time

```
        if(!prefs.getBoolean("ConversionDone", false)){
            String currentStringValue = prefs.String(PREF_LOGGEDIN_USER_USERID, 0);
            prefs.edit().remove(PREF_LOGGEDIN_USER_USERID).commit();
            prefs.edit().putLong(PREF_LOGGEDIN_USER_USERID, Long.parseLong(currentStringValue)).commit();
            prefs.edit().putBoolean("ConversionDone", true).commit();
        }
```

and at your next update you can remove it.